# Toggle field depending on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 
});

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#people").val() == 1)
        $("#personen1").show();
    else
        $("#personen1").hide();
        $("#personen2").hide();
        $("#personen3").hide();
        $("#personen4").hide();
        $("#personen5").hide();
        $("#personen6").hide();
        $("#personen7").hide();
        $("#personen8").hide();
        
}
```

```html
    <p>Personen:
       <input type="number" id="people" name="ppl" min="1" class="uniform-input number" value="1" required="">
    </p>
     <div id="personen1">
        <p>1. Person:
            <input id="personen1_person1" type="text" name="person_name" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="personen2">
        <p>1. Person:
            <input id="personen2_person1" type="text" name="person_name" />
        </p>
        <p>2. Person:
            <input id="personen2_person2" type="text" name="person2_name" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="personen3">
        <p>1. Person:
            <input id="personen3_person1" type="text" name="person_name" />
        </p>
        <p>2. Person:
            <input id="personen3_person2" type="text" name="person2_name" />
        </p>
        <p>3. Person:
            <input id="personen3_person3" type="text" name="person3_name" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

I have a people number input on my landingpage. I want to use the input value to add fields to my checkout. Like if the input is 5 I want 5 fields in my checkout page so the customer can fill in the names. The code above is not working correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: First of all you have multiple identical `ids`.

Comment: And `else` should be blocked to add multiple statements

Comment: Second of all indenting the statements in the else clause does not take the place of `{ ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and foremost mistake you are making is duplicating `id`s, which are supposed to be unique, else unintended effects may appear.

The next thing is, the snippet will not work because you haven't included `jQuery` library, which is more important than anything to execute the `$` function.

Thirdly, find these mistakes you have made:

1. You didn't bind the event with the input.
2. You need to check the input for the existence of id.
3. You aren't closing the `if` correctly.
4. You can compress the code a lot of effective ways, by using `class` or by using `id`s in a single `$` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  toggleFields();
  $("#people").on("keyup change", function () {
    toggleFields();
  });
});

function toggleFields() {
  $("#personen1, #personen2, #personen3, #personen4, #personen5, #personen6, #personen7, #personen8").hide();
  if ($("#people").val() < 9)
    $("#personen" + $("#people").val()).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Personen:
  <input type="number" id="people" name="ppl" min="1" class="uniform-input number" value="1" required="">
</p>
<div id="personen1">
  <p>1. Person:
    <input id="person1-1" type="text" name="person_name" />
  </p>
</div>
<div id="personen2">
  <p>1. Person:
    <input id="person2-1" type="text" name="person_name" />
  </p>
  <p>2. Person:
    <input id="person2-2" type="text" name="person2_name" />
  </p>
</div>
<div id="personen3">
  <p>1. Person:
    <input id="person3-1" type="text" name="person_name" />
  </p>
  <p>2. Person:
    <input id="person3-2" type="text" name="person2_name" />
  </p>
  <p>3. Person:
    <input id="person3-3" type="text" name="person3_name" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When I add `<div id="personen4">
  <p>1. Person:
    <input id="person4-1" type="text" name="person_name" />
  </p>
  <p>2. Person:
    <input id="person4-2" type="text" name="person2_name" />
  </p>
  <p>3. Person:
    <input id="person4-3" type="text" name="person3_name" />
  </p>
  <p>4. Person:
    <input id="person4-4" type="text" name="person4_name" />
  </p>
</div>`  and change the value="4" it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

*You should not have multiple ids with same value.*

That is not a right way of doing this, you should generate the HTML using JavaScript only:

```
// Sample code, you can create a function for this as well.
$(function(){

    var count = 5; // Change this count with the input field value.
    var _html = "";
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
        _html += '<p>'+(i+1)+'. Person:'
                    +'<input id="person'+(i+1)+'" type="text" name="person'+(i+1)+'_name" />'
                +'</p>';
    }

    $(".container").html(_html);

});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evevrvsa/)

Answer (score 0):

Every `id` attribute you use on a webpage has to be *unique* in the *entire document*, also -- you're using some kind of template to load when a user types a number but what if a user wants to add 10 people instead of 3 or 5? Individually adding cases will cause you much pain in the future.

I also understand that you want users to input a number and then get a certain amount of fields back from that, with that assumption made the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleFields();
});
```

will not work since it only gets executed once, *onload* of the page and doesn't get executed anymore after that since no events are bound.

```js
var insertPeople = function(n) {
    var amt = !isNaN(n) ? n : 1;
    var fieldStr = '';
    //using a for loop to 'build' the fields dynamically
    for (var i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
        var num = i + 1;
        fieldStr += '<p>'+ num +'. person<input type="text" id="person'+ num +'" name="person'+ num +'_name"></p>'
    }
    //append HTML to container
    $('#people-container').html(fieldStr);
}


//Use this to insert fields on page load instantly.
$(insertPeople);

//Use this if you would like a user to control the amount of fields through an input field.
$(function() { //shorthand for $(document).ready
    $('#people').on('keyup', function() {
        insertPeople($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="people" value="1" />
<div id="people-container"></div>
```

This code will loop for *n* times where *n* is the user input (validate the type of that yourself) and creates fields with ID's starting from 0 through the end point at the end of the loop. At the last step it appends the fields to a container, if this were a form then that form would simply be submit with those values.

Comment: **1.** You can use `$(document).ready(toggleFields);`  **2.** `var amt = $(this).val();` ==> `var amt = +$(this).val();` or use `parseFloat`, `parseInt`, ...

Comment: @Tushar very much correct except the OP needs this not on the document ready but rather when users input a value ^.^

Comment: The input is on the first page. Later on the saved value is used to add fields to my checkout. So there is no input in the checkout process. Isn't that document ready?

Comment: @Engineer007 I misunderstood in that case - I'll update my answer

Comment: @Engineer007 my code works in both cases, I added comments that describe the role of the function in each scenario, All you'd need is my `insertPeople` function and the `$(insertPeople)` line which automatically executes the function.